# How to remove bootstrap from Laravel 7 Project

Tags: laravel, authentication

I have created laravel 7 project without UI package installation. But I want to generate laravel built in login system. When I generate login system, Laravel UI CSS will override my existing designs.

Comment: Use git so you can revert any unwanted changes. Let us know how that went.

Answer (score 1):

If you uninstall default bootstrap in your project just type this command:

> npm remove bootstrap

npm remove bootstrap will remove everything from node_modules folder

Then check goto ->  package.json

```
"devDependencies": {
"axios": "^0.19",
"cross-env": "^7.0",
"jquery": "^3.2",
"laravel-mix": "^5.0.1",
"lodash": "^4.17.13",
"popper.js": "^1.12",
"resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.0",
"sass": "^1.15.2",
"sass-loader": "^8.0.0",
"vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
```

}

Note: if bootstrap is not shown in dependencies then your bootstrap is removed from Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `php artisan ui:auth --views` to only generate the views or just `php artisan ui:auth`

Answer (score 0):

You can run the npm uninstall bootstrap command to completely get rid of the package and it's dependencies.